# Finding an array of arrays... inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm dealing with 'arrays of arrays' and trying to test if all 'sets' contained in the second array are present in the first array.

```
var arr = [['Netherlands','PP3a'],['Austria','PP16a'],['Estonia','PP3a'],['Luxembourg','PP3a'],['Belgium','PP3a']];

var n   = [['Luxembourg','PP3a'],['Netherlands','PP3a'],['Belgium','PP3a']];
```

In my example https://jsfiddle.net/mnb8jddw/ they clearly are present, but the code (which incidentally seems to work with numbers), reads false.  I've obviously got myself confused and would really appreciate some help as I suspect I'm taking the wrong approach.

```
var arr = [
  ['Netherlands', 'PP3a'],
  ['Austria', 'PP16a'],
  ['Estonia', 'PP3a'],
  ['Luxembourg', 'PP3a'],
  ['Belgium', 'PP3a']
];
var n = [
  ['Luxembourg', 'PP3a'],
  ['Netherlands', 'PP3a'],
  ['Belgium', 'PP3a']
];

function searchForArray(haystack, needle) {
  var i, j, current;
  for (var i in haystack) {
    if (needle.length === haystack[i].length) {
      current = haystack[i];
      for (j = 0; j < needle.length && needle[j] === current[j]; ++j);
      if (j === needle.length)
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(searchForArray(arr, n)); // -1 = false
```

Comment: According to the code, the needle should be one subelement of n. For eg, `searchForArray(arr,n[0]);` would returns 3.

Comment: what index your function should return? the elements you search do not exist in that order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is the answer you are looking for, but if you are looking for a quick and dirty solution, you could try something like this:

```
const lookup = (ar, sets) => {
  // concatenate each entry in the searched array
  const _hashed = ar.map(i => i.join(''))
  return sets.every((set) => {
    // contatenate each entry to look for
    const _set = set.join('')
    // does the searched array contain the concatenated string?
    return _hashed.indexOf(_set) > -1
  })
}

console.log(lookup(arr, n)) // => true
```

Note that the order of the elements matters (ie: `['Luxembourg', 'PP3a']` will match, but `['PP3a', 'Luxembourg']` won't)

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnb8jddw/1/)

Comment: I'm really not sure why you call this 'Q&D'.  It does the job brilliantly and I much appreciate your help!

Comment: Q&D because `map` and `every` methods are not really optimized for speed, and, as stated, it won't fit every use cases. You may consider sorting the strings (`.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))`) if order matters!